# How to restrict routes redistributed into ISIS in IOS XR?

Tags: cisco-ios-xr, route-filter

I have a router running `Cisco IOS XR` with established L2 ISIS adjacency with a neighbor router. I would like to inject only the IPv4 address configured on loopback interface into the ISIS. The route for IPv4 address configured on `Loopback0` can be seen below:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#sh route 172.16.0.22/32
Sun Apr 18 20:13:11.393 UTC

Routing entry for 172.16.0.22/32
  Known via "local", distance 0, metric 0 (connected)
  Installed Apr 18 20:06:41.281 for 00:06:30
  Routing Descriptor Blocks
    directly connected, via Loopback0
      Route metric is 0
  Redist Advertisers:
    4 (protoid=4, clientid=21)

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#`
```

At first I tried with `route-policy` below:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#sh run route-policy allow-lo 
Sun Apr 18 20:15:02.546 UTC
route-policy allow-lo
  if destination in (172.16.0.22/32) then
    done
  else
    drop
  endif
end-policy
!

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#
```

This route policy was configured under ISIS configuration:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#sh run router isis 
Sun Apr 18 20:15:50.689 UTC
router isis lab
 is-type level-2-only
 net 49.0000.1720.1600.0022.00
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  redistribute connected route-policy allow-lo
 !
/* output removed for brevity */
```

As this did not seem to have affect, then I tagged the `172.16.0.22/32` route with tag `10` and tried with policy below:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#sh run route-policy allow-lo 
Sun Apr 18 20:19:39.017 UTC
route-policy allow-lo
  if tag eq 10 then
    done
  else
    drop
  endif
end-policy
!

RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#
```

Again, this had no affect. According to [Cisco documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/xr12000/software/xr12k_r4-0/routing/configuration/guide/rc40xr12k_chapter7.html#con_1158914) `destination` and `tag` seem to be the two reasonable attributes with `redistribution` attach point for filtering routes.

How to restrict routes redistributed into ISIS in IOS XR?

Comment: Do you need to specify `level-2` on your `redistribute` statement?

Comment: Do you mean `redistribute connected level-2 route-policy allow-lo`? If yes, then this didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround, I configured `Lo0` interface as a passive and advertised only passive interfaces into ISIS:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#sh run router isis lab
Mon Apr 19 11:01:50.732 UTC
router isis lab
 is-type level-2-only
 net 49.0000.1720.1600.0022.00
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  advertise passive-only
 !
 interface Loopback0
  passive
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  !
 !
  /* output removed for brevity */
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:PE2#
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to do "pass" instead of done.